# restoring usr/share/php with yum on centOS

Tags: php, centos, yum

my httpd service wont start/restart
possibly because i have nothing in my usr/share/php/ directory
how do i restore this paerticular directory using yum in ssh on centOS?
if i have virtual host paths in ssl.conf configurred improperly that wouldnt stop httpd from starting?
i need to fix this too but i think its the directory

Comment: Have you checked the error log yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a bit peculiar to find binary files in /usr/share - and anything else related to PHP would not prevent the webserver from starting.

Show us your error_log

Comment: hi, the error log showed nothing past 5 days ago, since apache hasnt been able to start. however i just removed apache/php/mysql all at once and then reinstalled and now the service is going again. im sure i already did that but maybe the order was important, probably the dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

yum install php

yum install mysql

yum install apache

or

yum update php

Comment: > yum install php gives conflict between zend-server-php-5.2 and zend-server-php-5.3.
> yum install zend-server-php-5.3 tells me that this is installed.
> yum repolist shows zend, zend_noarch, addons, atomic, base, c5-testing, extras, turbopanel-base, turbopanel-centos5, updates

> apache2ctl start 
gives command not found
start/restart Apache 2 in turbopanel services does nothing.
What command will tell me whats wrong with httpd?
Last line of the httpd log file from 5days ago was
[Sat Apr 23 10:10:29 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: mysql 5.1.56... already installed and latest version
yum install httpd gives packages httpd-2.2.8.1....centos.i386 already installed and latest update
but there is still nothing in usr/share/php
but httpd directory is in /etc/
does php in usr/share need to be restored?

Comment: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: remove zend-server-php-5.2

Comment: i will try this thanks
i did previously have mysql 5.5 installed but from atomic
i will try this way now

Comment: i didnt want to frustrate over another repository so i reinstalled everything (httpd/php/mysql) again and now the service is up again. it mustve been a dependency issue. but there is still nothing in usr/share/. I guess its supposed to be empty like symcbean has inferred below. sorry im trying to learn linux/centos as i go, im a n00b still. but when httpd restarted, i noticed Tomcat5.5 was "dead" but came alive again with an install and service restart. also i need to reinstall mcrypt now and try to configure mysql again. frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested answer:

`rpm -qf /usr/share/php`

`yum remove` whatever package that gives you. From the path it almost definitely looks like you'll want PHP.

`yum install` package

Comment: this didnt work but thanks anyhow cookie